# Custom columns in ToDoList stylesheets

Tags: xml, xslt

I'm not 100% sure that this is he correct place for this question since it's a programming question related to one software.
Anyway, I'm using *AbstractSpoon's ToDoList* and I created custom columns.
The software allows you to use customised xsl stylesheets to print tasks.
In thoose files, they use `<xsl:value-of select="@COMMENTS" />` to access a column's value. Now this only works with the default columns like `@ID` or `@ALLOCATEDBY` and I need to print values from my custom columns.
I found that the software give you a unique Id for every custom columns but I can't find how to make them work.
My custom column is called `PROJET` and its unique Id is `CUST_PROJET`.
Here is what I already tried

```
<xsl:value-of select="@CUST_PROJET" />
<xsl:value-of select="CUST_PROJET" />
<xsl:value-of select="@PROJET" />
<xsl:value-of select="PROJET" />
```

And none of them work.
EDIT:
The datafile look like this, but since the stylesheet file is used in the 'Print' function of the software, I'm not sure that they don't do anything on it before applying the xsl.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16" ?>
<TODOLIST PROJECTNAME="Tâches S.I." FILEFORMAT="9" EARLIESTDUEDATE="41578.00000000" NEXTUNIQUEID="138" FILENAME="Tâches S.I..tdl" FILEVERSION="204" CHECKEDOUTTO="BN655:JPWA">
<CUSTOMATTRIB ID="CUST_PROJET" LABEL="Projet" COLTITLE="Projet" TYPE="512" COLALIGN="1" SORTABLE="1" ENABLED="1" LISTDATA="Adressage
Base Editoriale
E.R.P.
..."/>

<TASK TITLE="Liste des tâches non prioritaires" ID="7" REFID="0" COMMENTSTYPE="849cf988-79fe-418a-a40d-01fe3afcab2c" ALLOCATEDBY="JPW" CREATEDBY="JPWA" PRIORITY="5" RISK="0" PERCENTDONE="0" CALCPERCENTDONE="3">
    <TASK TITLE="Mise en place de la gestion des impayés" ID="60" REFID="0" COMMENTSTYPE="849cf988-79fe-418a-a40d-01fe3afcab2c" ALLOCATEDBY="JPW" STATUS="1. NC" CREATEDBY="JPWA" PRIORITY="0" RISK="0" PERCENTDONE="0">
        <CATEGORY>Evolution</CATEGORY>
        <CUSTOMATTRIB ID="CUST_PROJET" VALUE="Base Editoriale"/>
    </TASK>
    <TASK TITLE="Modification des dates de livraison sur les commandes de ventes" ID="70" REFID="0" COMMENTSTYPE="849cf988-79fe-418a-a40d-01fe3afcab2c" ALLOCATEDBY="P1" STATUS="1. NC" CREATEDBY="P2" PRIORITY="0" RISK="0" PERCENTDONE="0">
        <PERSON>P1</PERSON>
        <CATEGORY>Evolution</CATEGORY>
        <CUSTOMATTRIB ID="CUST_PROJET" VALUE="E.R.P."/>
    </TASK>
</TASK>
...

<CATEGORY>Correction</CATEGORY>
...
<STATUS>1. NC</STATUS>
<STATUS>2. EC</STATUS>
...
<PERSON>P1</PERSON>
<PERSON>P2</PERSON>
...
</TODOLIST>
```

Does anybody know how to access custom column using the stylesheet ?

Comment: Please post the XML input file (AbstractSpoon data/config file) which the XSLT runs against.

Comment: It would also be helpful to see your current XSLT so far.